# How do I reference a sub-category using {categories} tag pair?

Tags: categories, relationships, gwcode-categories, child-categories

I am using the {categories} tag pair to link entries to their relevant section, however, when I use the following code it does not display child categories.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="section" category="{section_category_num}"}
<h1>{title}</h1>
{intro_text}
</div>
</article>

</section>

<section>
<article class="container">
{sub_section}
<div class="product eight columns alpha">
<div class="product_img">
<img src="{sub_section:product_photo}" title="" />
<div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="product_info">
<h4>{sub_section:categories limit="1"}<a href="/living-room/{category_url_title}">{sub_section:title}</a>{/sub_section:categories}</h4>
{sub_section:product_description}
</div>
</div>
{/sub_section}
</article>
</section>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Since this is a section page, what I want to be able to do is to reference the related entries child category url to link to the relevant sub section.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. I did attempt to use GWCode Categories but without success.

Comment: Is `{sub_section}` a native Relationship field, and you're trying to access the categories loop which belongs to the child entry?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're most of the way there - you just need to make sure you prefix *everything* within your child entry loop.

```
{sub_section:categories limit="1"}
    {sub_section:category_id}        
    {sub_section:category_url_title}
    {sub_section:category_name}
{/sub_section:categories}
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for the response. For some reason, this code simply outputs code in between the tag pair, and does not return actual values.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm wrong about the prefixing? What happens if you remove the inner prefixes (but keep the outer prefix)?

Comment: If I do it like this: {sub_section:categories }<a href="/living-room/{category_url_title}">{sub_section:title}</a> {/sub_section:categories} I get both the parent and the child category URL title. Is there a way to only display the child URL?

Comment: One more thought here. Without limit="" it loops through all the categories and shows the link with the parent url and then with the child url. I tried to eliminate the parent category with show="not 2", but for some reason that gets ignored. Ideas?

Comment: Ha! that worked. I reloaded the page again and this time the show="not 2" worked. So I am good. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that you only wanted a child category. You could also try removing the `limit`, and then wrapping the link in `{if parent_id != "0"}{/if}`.